# В Qt хронометраж программы в Debug и Release значительно отличаются

Tags: qt, openmp

Вкратце, написал решение диф уравнение в частных производным параллельным алгоритмом (с использованием OpenMP) и последовательным.
Прикол в том, что при Debug компиляции у меня последовательный алгоритм выполняется около 75-85 сек, а параллельный 50-55 сек. Вроде бы все ОК. Но стоит только скомпилировать в режиме Release, так параллельный алгоритм выполняется 25-30 сек, а последовательный 18-20 сек!!!
Так вот, может у кого то была такая же проблема?
Весь код скидывать не буду, боюсь не осилите. Скину фрагмент кода:

```
void DifferenceScheme::solveOMP()
{
    n = round((xMax - xMin) / xStep);
    m = round((tMax - tMin) / tStep);
    u = dMatrix(n + 1, dVector(m + 1, initValue));
    TridiagonalMatrix tm(n + 1);
    dVector F(n + 1);
    Progonka progonka(tm, F);
    double error;

    workTime = clock();
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        u[i][0] = w(xMin + i * xStep, tMin);
    }
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
    {
        u[0][i] = w(xMin, tMin + i * tStep);
        u[n][i] = w(xMax, tMin + i * tStep);
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        do
        {
#pragma omp parallel for
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                tm.lower[i - 1] = dLeft(i, j);
                tm.main[i] = dCenter(i, j);
                tm.upper[i] = dRight(i, j);
                F[i] = -1 * f(i, j);
            }
            tm.main[0] = tm.main[n] = 1;
            F[0] = -1 * (u[0][j] - w(xMin, tMin + j * tStep));
            F[n] = -1 * (u[n][j] - w(xMax, tMin + j * tStep));
            progonka.solveOMP();
#pragma omp parallel for
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                u[i][j] += progonka.x[i];
            }
            error = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                if (fabs(progonka.x[i]) > error)
                    error = fabs(progonka.x[i]);
        }
        while (error > accuracy);
    }
    workTime = clock() - workTime;
}
```

Comment: Вас смущает снижение времени в релизе или что в релизе параллельная реализация медленнее?

Comment: Во время счета вы видите загрузку всех ядер? Кстати, сколько их?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов меня смущает что в релизе параллельная реализация медленнее.

Comment: @gbg Нет, загрузку не смотрел, но как начинает крутить вентилятор слышно. Ядер 2. Это через диспетчер можно посмотреть? Или нужен спец софт?

Comment: @van9petryk достаточно диспетчера - в нем есть графики по ядрам.
и как вы время измерили?

Comment: В дополнение, я запустил программу на omp в релизе на сетке n = 1000001 m = 10 и О Чудо... параллельная 117 сек, последовательная 217 сек. Вроде бы все стало понятно. Тем не менее, у меня в арсенале еще программа на MPI, где я запускаю с той же сеткой при которой omp (27 сек) проигрывает последовательному алгоритму (17 сек), и получаю решение за (8 сек). Как такое вообще может быть? MPI же должен по идее медленнее работать чем OMP, а значит если бы проблема была в переключениях, то MPI должен был работать 27+ сек

Comment: @gbg double workTime = clock(); workTime = clock() - workTime. Ну а потом workTime / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC. Я не думаю что здесь проблема в измерении времени, потому что я и без измерения вижу что дольше выполняется

Comment: @van9petryk проблема не здесь. Попробуйте N побольше.

Comment: @gbg Что вы имеете в виду под N? размер сетки или количество ядер? У меня только два ядра. А размер сетки побольше я уже пробовал, решается быстрее на omp.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40517/discussion-between-gbg-and-van9petryk).

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, что N (размер матрицы) у вас маловато, и затраты на старт потоков оказываются сравнимы со временем выполнения.

Чтобы в этом убедиться, запустите ваш софт на большем N.

Comment: вы правы, но я здесь также причина в плохом расспараллеливании

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, моя ошибка что я везде писал #pragma omp parallel for.
Тем самым, я создавал и удалял постоянно потоки. Мне удалось подогнать время параллельной программы к времени последовательной изменением параллельности. Теперь после do { я делаю #pragma omp parallel, а возле каждого цикла #pragma omp for. таким образом потоки создаются и удаляются лишь вначале и в конце do{}